# SQL Server 2000: weird error: cannot convert VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm having a weird error that happens under weird circumstances.

The list of skill names I receive in the cursor `curLongSkills` is to be inserted into the table `tbl_new_skill_overview` if and only if they don't already exist. So I loop through the cursor as usual, and check whether it already exists before inserting.

The weird thing is that I receive the error `Syntax error converting the varchar value 'Some Random Skill' to a column of data type int.` on the line `SELECT @iCount = COUNT(ID)`.

However, this does *not* happen if I remove the `WHERE` clause in that statement. So if I comment or remove `WHERE Name = @sSkillName`, it won't give the error. It's as if it thinks that I'm assigning `@sSkillName` to `@iCount` just because I'm using `@sSkillName` in the `WHERE` clause of the same query.

Other ways of doing this will suffice provided that I can tell whether or not the skill has already been inserted into `tbl_new_skill_overview`. I don't necessarily have to do it this way.

I've also tried the following, which gives the same error:

```
SET @iCount = (
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Line_Count
FROM tbl_new_skill_overview
WHERE Name = @sSkillName
);
```

The server is running Microsoft SQL Server 2000 (I know, I know...).

Following is the entire SQL script.

```
DECLARE @sSkillName VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @iCount INT;

DECLARE curLongSkills CURSOR FOR (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name
    FROM tbl_new_skill
    WHERE Profile = 'long'
    AND Parent_ID IS NULL
)

OPEN curLongSkills;

FETCH curLongSkills INTO @sSkillName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @iCount = COUNT(ID)
    FROM tbl_new_skill_overview
    WHERE Name = @sSkillName; -- No error if this line removed.

    IF @iCount = 0 BEGIN
        PRINT @sSkillName;
        -- TODO: Insert skill
    END;

    FETCH curLongSkills INTO @sSkillName;
END;

CLOSE curLongSkills;
DEALLOCATE curLongSkills;
```

Comment: Weird. Have you tried `set @iCount = (select ...` ?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Yes, and I've updated the question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: can you post structure for tbl_new_skill and tbl_new_skill_overview?

Comment: @bobs: God, I'm stupid sometimes. The 'Name' column is incorrectly an INT, not VARCHAR.

Comment: I wondered about that.  And, it's good that your not any smarter than the rest of us.  Otherwise, we wouldn't need this site.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was stupidity.

The `Name` column in `tbl_new_skill_overview` was mistakenly put in as an `INT`, not a `VARCHAR`.

Thanks to all who responded, particularly *bobs* for asking me to show the database structure, at which point I realized the mistake.

Comment: Ah - seems obvious in hindsight, eh :)

Comment: Always the little things... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've never liked cursors - but as a cheeky alternative, you should be able to accomplish what you want without a cursor.

```
insert into tbl_new_skill_overview
select //columnNames
from tbl_new_skill
WHERE Profile = 'long'
AND Parent_ID IS NULL
and name not in
(select name from tbl_new_skill)
```

Comment: Thanks; turns out the 'Name' columns was incorrectly specified as INT, but it's nice to have your solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange occurrence for sure. I have no idea what's causing it, but to get around it, perhaps you could do something like this:

```
if not exists (select * from tbl_new_skill_overview where Name = @sSkillName) begin
    print @sSkillName;
    -- TODO: Insert skill
end
```

That is assuming you don't use @iCount for anything else later.

Comment: Thanks; turns out the 'Name' columns was incorrectly specified as INT, but it's nice to have your solution. :)